# obtener datos mysql y enviarlos por php a un email

Tags: php, html, mysql

mi problema es el siguiente tengo este codigo
`

```
if (!empty($nombre) && !empty($correo) && !empty($mensaje)) {
    $nombre = trim($nombre);
    $nombre = filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $correo = filter_var($correo, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $mensaje = htmlspecialchars($mensaje);
    $mensaje = trim($mensaje);
    $mensaje = stripslashes($mensaje);

    if(!filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un correo valido <br />';
    }
}else{
    $errores .= 'Porfavor rellena todos los campos';
}

if(!$errores){
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=restaurante','root','');
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrito");
        $statement->execute();
        $resultado = $statement->fetchAll();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    $enviar_a = 'correo@correo.com';
    $asunto_a = 'Asunto: Pedido desde la pagina de Restaurante vernnys';
    $mensaje_preparado = "De: $nombre \n";
    $mensaje_preparado .= "Correo: $correo \n";
    $mensaje_preparado .= "Mensaje: " . $mensaje;


    mail($enviar_a, $asunto_a, $mensaje_preparado);
    $enviado = 'true';
}
```

}
?>`

No se como hacer en la parte del

> try{}catch{}

para que me tome los datos que tengo en la base de datos y me lo concatene a mensaje y los envie junto con nombre, correo y mensaje
mi base de datos "carrito" solo tiene 2 columnas... producto y precio, solo quiero que me envie esta tabla a mi correo junto con todo lo anterior, alguien me podria decir como termino mi codigo ahi porfavor?!

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer tus resultados en un bucle `foreach`, concatenando en una variable y luego añadirla al final del mensaje.

También, el envío del mensaje debes hacerlo dentro del `try`, ya que si hay un error, tratará de enviar el mensaje, pero no habrá datos.

Además, la variable `$enviado` debe depender de lo que ocurra con `mail`, ya que `mail` devuelve `false` si hubo algún error. Setearla siempre a `true` no corresponde a la realidad.

**Nota muy importante: Aquí `$row["producto"]." - ".$row["precio"]`  debes escribir exactamente cómo se llaman tus dos columnas en la base de datos, porque he puesto esto: `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` indicando que me cree un array asociativo de nombres columnas->valor, con dada dato.**

La propuesta de código es esta:

```
if(!$errores){
    try {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=restaurante','root','');
            $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrito");
            $statement->execute();
            $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $strResultado="";
            foreach ($resultado as $row){
                $strResultado .= $row["producto"]." - ".$row["precio"].PHP_EOL;
            }

            $enviar_a = 'correo@correo.com';
            $asunto_a = 'Asunto: Pedido desde la pagina de Restaurante vernnys';
            $mensaje_preparado = "De: $nombre \n";
            $mensaje_preparado .= "Correo: $correo \n";
            $mensaje_preparado .= "Mensaje: " . $mensaje.PHP_EOL.$strResultado;

            $enviado= mail($enviar_a, $asunto_a, $mensaje_preparado);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```